# Export to excel style classes for page

Tags: css, stylesheet, export-to-excel

I am exporting a jsp page to excel by setting the content type to 'vnd.ms-excel'. Now i want to set the margins and page size for the opened excel sheet. so i am using the following piece of code withing my style tags.

```
@page
{   margin:0.1in 0.0in 0.0in 0.1in;
    mso-header-margin:0.1in;
    mso-footer-margin:0.1in;
    size: 15in 12in;
    mso-page-orientation: landscape;
}
```

Now in the opened up excel, the margins are set as mentioned, but the page size and orientations are not set. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Also let me know if I can specify scaling for the page to adjust to 85% of normal size.

Thanks!

Cheers,Deena